# postgresql XOR Join on array value or null?

Tags: postgresql, join

I have two tables, Foo and Bar, I'd like to join them together so BarID gets the prize based on having a key that is in the array, or if there's no array set up, it defaults as if every key unlocks the prize.

```
>Table Foo
fooID | someArray    | prize
----------------------------------
 1    | {10,20,30}   | 'Winner'
 2    | {10}         | 'Grand prize'
 3    | null         | 'Participant'
```

(That's not a string for someArray, it's a valid [postgresql type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html).)

```
>Table Bar 
BarID | Key
------------
 1    | 10
 2    | 20
 3    | 30
 4    | 40
 5    | 40
 6    | 40
```

I've tried this below:

```
SELECT
    Foo.fooID,
    Bar.prize
FROM Foo
LEFT JOIN Bar ON Bar.Key = ANY(someArray)
```

I have minimal success with this, when I put in a WHERE clause such as

```
WHERE Bar.BarID = 3
```

My results are simply 'Winner'm but I also want to get 'Participant'. If I set up my WHERE to include nulls:

```
WHERE 
    Bar.BarID = 3
  OR
    Foo.someArray = null
```

I still do not get my null values out.

No where clause returns all combinations of values, including the nulls.

I'm not really sure how to get this behaviour I want. I can get all, or I can get just one set of values, but not both.

To give examples, if I were to do the join for BarID = 1, I should get "Winner", "Grand prize" and "participant". If I were to select for BarID 5, I would only get Participant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Foo.someArray IS NULL
```

The equality operator always yields `NULL`, not `TRUE` when applied to a `NULL` value. To test a column whether it holds the `NULL` value, you need the above expression, not <strike>`Foo.someArray = NULL`</strike>.

[More about that in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparison.html).

You also have to put it in your `JOIN` condition, not in a `WHERE` clause, as @Michael commented. Like:

```
LEFT JOIN Bar ON Bar.Key = ANY(Foo.someArray) OR Foo.someArray IS NULL
```

If you put it in the `WHERE` clause, you might also find rows where `Foo.someArray IS NOT NULL`, but has different prizes. With a `LEFT JOIN`, if (and only if) no row is found in `Foo` for a given `Bar`, `NULL` values will be appended for all columns of `Foo`, including `someArray`. This would fool a check for `NULL` in a `WHERE` condition.

Comment: That's right, though I'm not sure that this change will yield the desired results. If I understand what are the desired results.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Good point. I ammended my answer accordingly and added some info about that.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ON COALESCE(Bar.Key = ANY(someArray),TRUE)
```

Comment: This expression carries the (theoretical) flaw, that it also yields TRUE if `Bar.Key` IS NULL, which is not what we want.